# Surface cannot be created with nurbs curves by pressing F key

Tags: edit-mode, nurbs-surface

I followed several tutorial to create a nurbs curve, and duplicate it in edit mode. Of course I pressed <kbd>A</kbd> key to select all points and <kbd>F</kbd> key to create surface. But there was no surface be created, a start point of one curve and an end point of another point were connected instead. 
[image: Ready to press F key]
[image: Final result after pressing F key]

Is there anybody get any idea about this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to use one of the Nurbs Surface types. *Add* > ***Surface*** > *Nurbs Curve*
[image: add menu]

A **Curve**, whether a nurbs or bezier is only a stroke. It can not have volume, it is only ever a line.
A **Surface** is a full 3D solid that can have volume. All the expected commands will work: Fill <kbd>F</kbd>, Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> etc.